# How do you represent "secondary keys" in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a list of data that I want to relate to some `ownerId`, but the list can exceed row size limits, so I want to split this list across multiple rows. Each entry in this list has its own id, which is unique per owner. I was looking at composite keys (`ownerId:entryId`), but the main operation I need is to read this data in bulk (read all entries for `ownerId`). What is the best way to go about structuring this data?

Example:

```
ownerId | entryId | data
--------|---------|--------
OwnerA  | 1       | aaaaa
OwnerA  | 2       | bbbbb
OwnerB  | 1       | ccccc
```

Note that `ownerId` here is a SQL generated id, and `entryId` is an externally set id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that consumers of your query will filter on ownerId instead of entryId (i.e. the vast majority of `WHERE` clauses in your table will filter on ownerId as opposed to entityId), then you could get significant mileage simly by creating a composite clustered key/index on `(ownerId,entryId)`.  I say this because relational indexes use the first column as the primary sort criteria, so as long as you're filtering based on `ownerId`, under-the-hood, rows can be retrieved with `INDEX UNIQUE SCAN` operations as opposed to `TABLE FULL SCAN` operations.

That being said, if you'll have to be filtering both on `ownerId` and `entityId` independently (i.e. you'll have several queries in which the `WHERE` clause will be of the format `WHERE ownerId = {specific_owner_id}` and several other queries in which the `WHERE` clause will be of the format `WHERE entityId = {specific_entity_id}`, you might want to consider having both a `PRIMARY KEY`/`CLUSTERED INDEX` on `(ownerId, entityId)` and a unique index on `(entityId, ownerId)`:

```
  CREATE TABLE t (
    ownerId INT NOT NULL,
    entityId INT NOT NULL,
    /*
    ...all other values ...
    */
    CONSTRAINT PK_t PRIMARY KEY (ownerId, entityId)
  );
  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX t_entity_owner ON t (entityId, ownerId);
```

If you do this, both queries which filter on `ownerId` and `entityId` can take advantages of `INDEX SCAN` operations.

That being said, this type of configuration will be most optimal if table `t`
is used more for `READ` operations than for `WRITE` operations.  Should your table be more `WRITE` heavy, then the time taken to modify each of the indexes could outweigh the benefits of more efficient query reads.

Comment: I think the first option works fine for my use case given that I would have been fine just storing these entries in a single row if not for the size limitation. I guess it doesn't technically matter how the sorting works, but it's interesting to know that the sorting happens on first column and not necessarily the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need a composite primary key, i.e.:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t (
  ...
  
  PRIMARY KEY (ownerId, entryId)
);
```

and some separate index for `ownedId`, for example [in postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/indexes-types.html) hash index might be a good fit.